# Bootstrap _reboot.scss overriding PrimeNG styles

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5, primeng

Bootstrap seems to be overriding my PrimeNG styles, more specifically with it's _reboot.scss file. I have included the part's where I have referenced it in my styles.scss and angular.json. I have done some poking around and I have seen it get fixed in vanilla setup with just html and not in an angular environment.

In my styles.scss I have the following at the top:

```
@import 'modern-normalize/modern-normalize.css';
@import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
@import 'bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons';
@import "primeicons/primeicons.css";
@import "primeflex/primeflex.css";
@import "primeng/resources/primeng.min.css";
```

And then in my angular.json I have the following:

```
"styles": [
    "modern-normalize/modern-normalize.css",
    "bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css",
    "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
    "primeicons/primeicons.css",
    "primeflex/primeflex.css",
    "primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
    "src/styles.scss",
    {
        "input": "src/theme-light.scss",
        "bundleName": "light",
        "inject": false
    },
    {
        "input": "src/theme-dark.scss",
        "bundleName": "dark",
        "inject": false
    }
],
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since it may take a lot of time to approve my edits on [@Kino101 's answer](https://I%20also%20had%20this%20problem%20after%20updating%20my%20PrimeNG%20version%20to%20%3E=16.4.%20%20It%20appears%20that%20PrimeNG%20CSS%20(primeng.min.css)%20is%20now%20shipped%20as%20layers,%20which%20changes%20the%20selectors%20priority.%20%20More%20info%20here%20%5Bhere%5D(https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/13757).%20%20A%20solution%20is%20to%20give%20bootstrap%20a%20%22layer%22%20with%20a%20lower%20level.%20To%20achieve%20this,%20simply%20move%20the%20boostrap%20and%20primeng%20CSS%20references%20from%20the%20styles%20section%20of%20your%20angular.json%20to%20your%20main%20css%20file%20as%20follow:%20%20**styles.css**%20%60%60%60css%20@import%20%22../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css%22%20layer(bootstrap);%20@import%20%22../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css%22;%20%60%60%60%20%20After%20that%20We%20need%20to%20set%20priority%20since%20We%20can%20not%20add%20the%20%60@layer%60%20tag%20to%20specify%20layer%20order%20in%20existing%20angular%20%60css/scss%60%20:%20it%20will%20remove%20by%20angular%20compilation.%20We%20need%20to%20create%20CSS%20file%20let%27s%20say%20%60layer.css%60%20like%20this%20%20%20**layer.css**%20%60%60%60css%20@layer%20bootstrap,%20primeng;%20%60%60%60%20%20Finally%20import%20%60layer.css%60%20in%20%60index.html%60%20file%20**index.html**%20%60%60%60html%20%20%20...%20%20%20%3Clink%20rel=%22stylesheet%22%20type=%22text/css%22%20href=%22assets/styles/layer.css%22%3E%20%20%20...%20%60%60%60)
Here 's the full answer that works after updating to primng >= 16.4

It appears that PrimeNG CSS (primeng.min.css) is now shipped as layers, which changes the selectors priority.

More info here [here](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/13757).

A solution is to give bootstrap a "layer" with a lower level.
To achieve this, simply move the boostrap and primeng CSS references from the styles section of your `angular.json` to your main `css` file as follow:

**styles.css**

```css
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" layer(bootstrap);
@import "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css";
```

After that We need to set priority since We can not add the `@layer` tag to specify layer order in existing angular `css/scss` : it will remove by angular compilation.
We need to create CSS file let's say `layer.css` like this

**layer.css**

Create this file in your project assets folder (e.g., assets/styles/layer.css), it should contain the following.

```css
@layer bootstrap, primeng;
```

Finally import `layer.css` in `index.html` file
**index.html**

```html
  ...
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/styles/layer.css">
  ...
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue which I solved by switching from ***css*** to ***scss*** and importing only few components from bootstrap and ignoring the reboot file.

**_bootstrap.scss**

```
// Configuration
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables-dark";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/maps";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/utilities";    

// Layout & components
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/root";
//@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/reboot";

// Custom reboot if needed (i.e. .table, .h1, ...)

// Layout & components
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/containers";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/grid";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/tables";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/forms";

// Helpers
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/helpers";

// Utilities
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/utilities/api";
```

**_primeng.scss**

```
@import 'node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css';
@import "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/saga-green/theme.css";
@import "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.css";
```

**styles.scss**

```
@import 'bootstrap';
@import 'primeng';
```

Comment: This may no longer work if you are using primeng >= 16.4, In that case refer to [this answer instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77757968/11836885)

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem after updating my PrimeNG version to >=16.4.

It appears that PrimeNG CSS (primeng.min.css) is now shipped as layers, which changes the selectors priority.

More info [here](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/13757).

A solution is to give bootstrap a "layer" with a lower level.
To achieve this, simply move the boostrap and primeng CSS references from the styles section of your angular.json to your main css file as follow:

**styles.css**

```css
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" layer(bootstrap);
@import "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace the primeng in top of the styles and check

```
@import "primeicons/primeicons.css";
@import "primeflex/primeflex.css";
@import "primeng/resources/primeng.min.css";
@import 'modern-normalize/modern-normalize.css';
@import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
@import 'bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons';
```

Comment: This didn't exactly help. Seems when I have it in my angular workspace it works and when I have the project as it's own standalone project it has issues. Everything is imported and installed exactly the same. Would running the npm install command make a difference if I had perhaps installed primeng first?